# Formatting JSON output using map method - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I'm lacking some understanding on using the map method.

Using json output with no mapping

```
format.json  { render :json => @categories }
```

gives me the following output

```
[{"created_at":"2012-10-20T01:16:35+11:00","id":1,"name":"bathroom renovations","updated_at":"2012-10-20T01:16:35+11:00"}]
```

using json with mapping

```
format.json  { render :json => @categories.map(&:name) }
```

gives me this output

```
["bathroom renovations"]
```

How can I get my output to look like

```
[{"id":"1","name":"bathroom renovations"}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the following may work for you:

```
  format.json {render json: @categories.map{|category| {:id => category.id, :name =>  category.name} }}
```